# Does someone know how to write cases environment in org-mode to export to wordpress?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Using

```
\[
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} &, x\in (0,1)\\
0 &, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
```

does not export correctly, and the equation does not appear in the html page.

Comment: What does "does not export correctly" mean? Do you get anything in your `ltxpng` directory? Anything useful in `/tmp/orgtexXXXXXXX.log` files?

Comment: We have to define \begin{equation} environment. For some reason, it does not work with \[.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} &, x\in (0,1)\\
0 &, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```